# Problem integrating ASP.net Ajax user control as Web Part in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: asp.net-ajax, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I created a user control in Visual Studio in .Net framework 3.5 and using Ajax Toolkit 3.5 and then added the Star Rating Ajax control to the user control.

Now I want to add this user control as a webpart to a sharepoint 2010 website. Since the user control already has a asp:ToolkitManager to do the work of script manager, adding this webpart to a page on the MOSS site gives a lot of errors. Currently, I have retained the asp:ToolkitManger in the user control.

The error I get whenever I open the MOSS page containing the user control is **"PageRequestManager cannot be initialized more than once".**

I have no idea how to go about it. Any suggestions are welcome.

**EDIT**: I believe the sharepoint master page has a script manager of its own. I can't remove it because the other pages will suffer. How do I modify the user control in Visual Studio so that it includes the ajax update panel but refers to the sharepoint script manager.

Comment: Also, the user control is working fine in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the parent control or page already has ScriptManager defined...

Comment: i think so too, but how do i get rid of the problem?

Comment: you can look into using the ScriptManagerProxy for your control/page, pls mark as answered if this solves your issue

Comment: sorry. can't mark this as answer. I had to change my approach. Currently i'm trying to add Ajax Control toolkit directly to sharepoint and then use it. Refer to the "Edit" in the question

Comment: Had to remove the ToolKit manager before deploying to Sharepoint. But kept it for testing in Visual Studio